# Creating Themes with Liferay 7.0

Tags: themes

While creating a theme in Liferay 7 as per the doc https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/113737977

`buildtheme` was successful, but while running `buidcss`, it shows the following error, please suggest

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/com.liferay.sass.compiler.api/2.0.1/com.liferay.
sass.compiler.api-2.0.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/jruby-complete/9.2.7.0/jruby-complete-9.2.7.0.jar
Was passed main parameter 'sass.dir=/' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
Usage: java -jar com.liferay.css.builder-3.0.0.jar [options]

Execution failed for task ':wars:cbdrm:buildCSS'.

Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit
value 1* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option toget more log output.BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 2):

Liferay has updated his css builder to 3.0.0 version but your gradle plugin were using 2.1.3. So, Update your build.gradle theme by adding the line below inside the dependencies:

cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "2.1.3"

[check this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f61Q7.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, its working.

Comment: It seems this bug arise on Friday 24th May. What caoused it? A misconfiguration?

Comment: *By default, the plugin creates a configuration called cssBuilder and adds a dependency to the latest released version (before of Friday 24th was 2.1.3, after it updated to 3.0.0) of the Liferay CSS Builder.